# EOSLime with Kylin: Account Creation

Tags: eosjs, accounts, ram, javascript, account-creation

EOSLime does not seem to be able to create accounts with Kylin chain thru my method. It produces an error that there is insufficient RAM.

My method:

```
let default_a = eoslime.Account.load('...','...');
eoslime.Provider.defaultAccount = default_a; 
let dummy = await eoslime.Account.createRandom();
```

And the error string:

```
Error: the string "{\"code\":500,\"message\":
\"Internal Service Error\",\"error\":{\"code\":3080001,
\"name\":\"ram_usage_exceeded\",\"what\":\"Account 
using more than allotted RAM usage\",\"details
\":[{\"message\":\"account la5414bbb2ce has 
insufficient ram; needs 2996 bytes has 0 bytes\",\"file
\":\"resource_limits.cpp\",\"line_number\":213,\"method
\":\"verify_account_ram_usage\"}]}}" was thrown, throw 
an Error :)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process
/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

There was an opened issue in the repository. It was fixed today. You can get the updated eoslime code from the development branch. The fix is going to be uploaded on master branch and npm through the next week

Comment: ok i will try it out